# Issues when writing a server that handles both TCP and UDP server

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp, udp

I am writing a server program as a part of assignment that handles both a TCP and a UDP client. I am writing this by select function. My TCP server is great but my UDP server is not working fine.

My first line of each server logic is the line "Correctly reached UDP/TCP server part"
Line in the TCP server is printing correctly but not the UDP part.

The main purpose of the program is given a book name, I will search in the file and display the authorname. I have to handle both the tcp and the udp part. Thanks in advance.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char *line=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* MAXLINE); //line contains each line from the books.d file 
char *line_camel=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLINE); //allocating memory for the charecter pointers
char *title=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLINE);//allocating memory to hold the title from read from the client
char *search= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLINE);//allocating memory to store the search string 
char *temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLINE);
char authorname[MAXLINE]= "No Book\n";
authorname[7]='\n';
char *noresult="No Book\n"; //pointer to a charecter array
char semicolon=':';
int port; //used to store the port number
int listenfd; //listen fd for the socket address structure
int udpfd;
int connfd; //connfd
int maxfdp1;    
int nready;
socklen_t len;
fd_set rset;
FILE *fp; //File pointer 
int n;
int end;
pid_t childpid; //for fork system call
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; //declaring the socket address structure
if(argc != 2)// if the user has not given a port address through the parameters
{
    port = SERV_PORT; //assign the default port address
}
else
{
    port = atoi(argv[1]); //assign the user entered port number
}

listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //The server accepts the connections from the client
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));//clearing the contents of the socket address structure
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;//assigning IPV4 as the family for the socket address structure
servaddr.sin_port = htons(port); //converting from host to network order
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); //binding the socket address structure
Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);//specifying the maximum backlog connections

udpfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
bzero ( &servaddr, sizeof ( servaddr ) );
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl ( INADDR_ANY );
servaddr.sin_port = htons( port );

Bind(udpfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );

signal(SIGCHLD, sig_chld);
FD_ZERO ( &rset );
maxfdp1 = max ( listenfd, udpfd ) + 1;

fp = fopen("/home/631/common/books.d", "r");
while(true)
{
    FD_SET ( listenfd, &rset ); 
    FD_SET ( udpfd, &rset );

    if ( ( nready = select ( maxfdp1, &rset, 0, 0, 0 ) ) < 0 )
        continue;

    if ( FD_ISSET ( listenfd, &rset ) ) 
    {
        printf("Correctly reached the tcp part of the server\n");
        len = sizeof ( cliaddr ); 
        for(; ;)
        {
        errno = 0;
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, NULL, NULL);      
        if(errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        else
            break;
        }
        if ( ( childpid = Fork ( ) ) == 0 ) 
        {
                Close ( listenfd );
                while((n = Readline(connfd, title, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                {
                    title[n-1] = '\0';//explicitly putting a '\0' at the end of the input query to make it a  c-string
                    title=convert_tolower(title);//convert to lower case and catching it back
                    while( Fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL )// reading each line from the server
                    {
                        string_copy(line_camel, line); //copying the line read to another line for result 
                        line=convert_tolower(line);//convert the line to lowercase
                        search= strstr(line, title); //checking if there is a substring with title (bookname) in the line
                        if( search != NULL && search[strlen(title)] == semicolon)
                        {                          
                        temp = strchr(line_camel, semicolon); //retrieving the substring from the earlier stored line 
                        end= strlen(temp); //always the last but one and the last by one plus one indices are '\0' and '\n'
                        temp[end-2] = '\n';// this place has : but we need to over write it with \n if we want to transfer
                        temp[end-2+1] ='\0';//mark the end of the string
                        ++temp;// *(temp) has : but we want to skip that charecter. if we dereference temp, we have ':'
                        string_copy(authorname, temp);//copying to author
                        //authorname[strlen(authorname)] = '\n'; //mark a '\n' charecter to transmit to the client
                        }
                    }      
                    end=strlen(authorname);
                    Writen(connfd, authorname, strlen(authorname));//wrting the saved authorname to the socket 
                    string_copy(authorname,noresult);//resetting it back 
                    authorname[7]='\n';
                    rewind(fp);//rewind the file pointer to the start of the file
                }       
                Close ( connfd ); 
                exit ( 0 );
        }
        Close ( connfd );
    }
    if ( FD_ISSET ( udpfd, &rset ) ) 
    {
        printf("Correctly reached the udp part of the server ");
        len = sizeof ( cliaddr );
        n = recvfrom ( udpfd, title , MAXLINE, 0, NULL, NULL);
        sendto( udpfd, title, strlen(title), 0, ( SA* ) &cliaddr, len );
        rewind(fp);//rewind the file pointer to the start of the file
    }
}
Close(listenfd);
Fclose(fp);
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Add a tag C ? You got several bugs that the C people can find more easily, such as title[n-1] = '\0'; (Think what happens with title="C", n=1)
Maybe move things to functions.

Comment: Please show how you call your program using udp once it is running.

Comment: When I run the server and a tcp client, everything is fine. when I run the server and the udp client, not even the first statement in if ( FD_ISSET ( udpfd, &rset ) )  is being executed. Dont know why?

Comment: Maybe you do not get an udp package, nobody send? Check te returnvalue of udpfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); And comment out the tcp part,or try examples (search for udp + select + C)

Comment: Use `printf("Correctly reached the udp part of the server ");` with \n. Now it can be cached and you do not know if the lean is reached.

Answer (score 1):

I tried you code. It worked. (Of course, just the TCP/UDP parts. Rest commented out):

> Correctly reached the udp part of the server
>   Correctly reached the
>   tcp part of the server

Few suggestions:

Capture `tcpdump` on the client and server side. Examine the traces.

Is the UDP client really sending the packet?

As suggested by WalterA     in comments, have `\n` in the printf

.